# Get facebook events around location

Tags: facebook-graph-api, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook-fql

I want to get some information about the facebook events . Those information is :

1. Get list of public events filtered by either location or start time.
2. Get list of people attending the event .
3. Get the users friends who are attending the event .

I have done the last two where i user fql query to get the list of people or list of friends attending but i was not able to get the list of public events and also list filtered by location maybe name or lat/long and start time .

Also i am getting the list of people attending on a specific event id which i have to do for every event i get separately . Is there any way that i get the data of all three pooints in single query so that i recieve the events in a location and also its list of people and list of freinds attending ?

Can you help me in getting the list of events filtered by location and also by start time

Thanks

Comment: Can you help me in obtaining third , i want to get lit of friends attending a particular event whose id i have..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible indeed to receive events using location based "search" To do so you'll need the longitude and latitude coordinates of the location you want to search and a access_token with user_events permission (i think you could also use the public search)

Here's an FQL example how can you get all the events nearby of a location. (this searches from your and your friends events):

```
$lat = "40";
$long = "30";

// using offset gives us a "square" on the map from where to search the events
$offset = 0.4;

$events = 'SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND start_time > '. $created_time .' OR uid = me()) AND start_time > '. $created_time .' AND venue.longitude < \''. ($long+$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude < \''. ($lat+$offset) .'\' AND venue.longitude > \''. ($long-$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude > \''. ($lat-$offset) .'\' ORDER BY start_time ASC '. $limit;
```

The trick itself lies in the venue.longitude and venue.latitude useage. To get events from a city, just get the city coordinates and adjust the offset to your needs. If you don't know how to use FQL please look into [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)